# How to handle Json node with a name like #text

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization

I have a part in my Json who's like this :

```
"image":[{"#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34\/84504153.jpg","size":"small"}]
```

So I made a class like

```
public class Image
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}
```

The Json come from a REST Api and I deserialize the result with Json.Net

```
var content = await LastFmMethods.GetUserAsync(userName.ToString());
LastfmUserRootObject rootUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LastfmUserRootObject>(content);
```

But I'm never able to get this part :

> "#text":"http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/84504153.jpg"

And I'm pretty sure it's because the # before "text".
How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the property name in the [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of a [`DataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, or the [`PropertyName`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_PropertyName.htm) property of a [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
[DataContract]
public class Image
{
    [DataMember(Name="#text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string size { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public class Image
{
    [JsonProperty("#text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string size { get; set; }
}
```

If you use `DataMemberAttribute`, don't forget to add the [`DataContract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, and that data contract serialization is [opt-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx), so you'll need to add `DataMember` to all the attributes you want to serialize.